# Index storing in MatLab

Tags: matlab, indexing, multiple-columns

I've got this code:

```
minimum_value_1000 = chl_september_ind;
minimum_value_logic = (chl_september_ind < 0.001);
minimum_value_1000(minimum_value_logic) = 0;
```

There are several raw and columns in it and what I really need is to know in which column it starts to be 0 for every raw, and store the number of a column where it starts to be 0 for every raw either. I know, it is a pretty simple operation but I'm kind of frustrating and tried several ways to do it.

Comment: Please post your attempts and explain what doesn't work with them. Also, you say "in which column it starts to be 0 for every row". Do you want to index of the _first_ zero? Or can there be several runs of zeros in each row and you want the starting index of _all_ of them? You should also post an example with desired input and output, to clarify

Comment: Ok, next time I will. For now I've dealt with my issue. Yes, I wanted to index of the first zero only, but there was a sequence) Thank you for your answer.